# Environmental Variable for current domain

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop edition

I want to use environmental variable for currently joined domain just like I use `$USER` to bring current user.
From what I read there are few variables for that, but none seems to work for me.
I also cannot see those variables as active when I type `env` command.

I would appreciate a solution on how to enable that variable or how to make my own variable by pulling current domain name from the system somehow.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this ?

```
DOMAIN=$( hostname )
```